# Take interest and give away stuff instead

Tags: practical-islam, riba

If I have 300 USD of interest in cash and a jewellery of 300 USD from halaal money, if I need cash right now, can I give the jewellery to charity instead and take the interest money?

Comment: IMO what you are asking for requires a fatwa from a well-versed scholar. And we are not a fatwa site. My impression after reading some fatwas is that it might rather still be considered as haraam money which you shouldn't accept.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requires a fatwa and we are not a fatwa site.